# Can't Install Red5 Demos over LAN - Error: NetConnection.Connect.Failed

Tags: flash, ubuntu, installation, red5

I just installed Red5 1.0, followed all the demo file instructions and can't install any demos.

I get a "Error: NetConnection.Connect.Failed" error when I try to run the demo installer from a computer on the LAN...

I have no GUI on the Red5 server machine, pls help.

Comment: The demos are downloaded from an online repository. I goes this online repository is down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might simply manualy copy the .war files from http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/snapshots/

Comment: Do you know where I should copy these files to?

Comment: @user989990 copy the downloaded war file to webapps folder of red5 server. Then restart red5 service. Now red5 server automatically extract and deploy the application.